# mvc4 dropdownList insert NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I search a lot here and find something like this to make dropdown list
this is my model :

```
public class Profits
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
       [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateInput { get; set; }
        public UserProfile User { get; set; }
        public Categories CategoryName { get; set; }//foreign key
          public   int CategoryID { get; set; }
    }

 public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        public UserProfile User { get; set; }


    }
```

this is my controller: 
This pass my data for dropDownList...

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var dba = new WHFMDBContext();
    var query = dba.Categories.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name });
    ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Name", 3);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
        [InitializeSimpleMembership]
        public ActionResult Create(Profits profits)
        {
            var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
            var profit = new Profits
            {
               Value= profits.Value,
               Description = profits.Description,
               DateInput =profits.DateInput,
               CategoryName =profits.CategoryName,// ???
                User = user,

            };
            db.Profits.Add(profit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

My View :

```
@model WebHFM.Models.Profits



@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profits</legend>


    <div class="editor-field">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList) ViewBag.Id, "--Select One--") 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
        </div>...
```

This insert data to database but `CategoryName_Id` is `NULL` what am I missing ?
and `CategoryName = profits.CategoryName` this is a foreign key to Categories in Profits  `public Categories CategoryName { get; set; }`

Comment: the problem is : i see data from db.Categories in my dropdownlist but when i choose some option from this ddl  and add some value for others Component (from EditorFor) .They have inserted into DB without choosen category from ddl instead category i have NULL.Thanks for patience

Comment: Does your profits class have CategoryName or CategoryID. In your example it is CategoryName, but what you are setting your dropdownlist to return is Id?

Comment: Is Categories CategoryName a list of categories, or a single category?

Comment: I'm going with that meaning it is a single category object.

Comment: @user2026573 I can answer this question but i need to know how your model is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your profits class, add this:

```
Profits
{
  int CategoryID {get;set;}
}
```

modify your cshtml. Change

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList) ViewBag.Id, "--Select One--")
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (SelectList) ViewBag.Id, "--Select One--")
```

alter your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Profits profits)
        {
            var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
            var category = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(o => o.CategoryId == profits.CategoryID);
            var profit = new Profits
            {
               Value= profits.Value,
               Description = profits.Description,
               DateInput =profits.DateInput,
               CategoryName = category,
               User = user
            };
            db.Profits.Add(profit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

What this will do is change your dropdownlist to return the selected CategoryID. The markup will look like:

```
<select name="CategoryID" />
```

On your postback, this will bind to your new Profits.CategoryID. You then use that to make a datbase query to get the selected category object which you then assign to Profits.CategoryName.

Comment: Ok I see now. You can replace your @Html.EditorFor() with @Html.Textbox() is what I'm saying here. You WILL get a nullref on model.CategoryName since you are not passing in a model.

Comment: In Profits.CategoryName is that a list of categories or a single category?

Comment: this is working for the db correctly.thanks i know see categoryId but in index.cshtml i see categoryId "0"

Comment: You need to pass your model to your view. WHen I get some time I'll add how to do that for you and why. If you wouldn't mind though, at least give me an up-vote for answering your original question.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Sorry, I thought I understood your problem yesterday, but I realize that I don't. What do you mean you see categoryID "0"? Can you indicate what you are expecting to see, and what you are actually seeing?

Comment: in MSSQL Server I see right info.Table profit with column named =CategoryName_id with with right data (1 or 2 or whatever is my primary key of table Categories) but in my index view where i should see this categoryNames. I see only Number - 0 everywhere.Basicly in my View I want to see html table with columns(name(Category),value , description,dataInput..)

Comment: Hate to tell you this, but this is a new question. Create a new question and post your Index Controller and your index.cshtml. It's a very easy solution that you need for it, but it doesn't make much sense for me to tack it onto the end of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Create() Action Return `return View();` without passing the model into view method parameters .

Comment: and what should have here becauser it's not a View(query) i think

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would suggest without looking at your model. PopulateCategoriesDropDownList lives in the same controller as your create action

```
private void PopulateCategoriesDropDownList(object selectedCategories = null)
    {
        var categoriesQuery = from d in _dataSource.Categories
                         orderby d.Name
                         select d;
        ViewBag.CategoryId= new SelectList(categoriesQuery, "CategoryId", "Name", selectedCategories);
    }
```

**Then your action like this.**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
      PopulateCategoriesDropDownList();
    return View();
   }


    [HttpPost]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public ActionResult Create(Profits profits)
    {
         var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId ==       WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        var profit = new Profits
        {
           Value= profits.Value,
           Description = profits.Description,
           DateInput =profits.DateInput,
           CategoryName =profits.CategoryName,// ???
            User = user,

        };
        db.Profits.Add(profit);
        db.SaveChanges();
        PopulateCategoriesDropDownList(profit.CategoryId);
       return View(profit);
    }
```

**In your View:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Pick Category")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
    </div><br/>
```